# cover div adding a margin

Tags: css, compiler-construction, margin

i have a `#cover` `div` with the following css

```
#cover {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.4;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9000;
}
```

i want it to cover the entire (viewed) page like so

[image]

however when i scroll down i see this

[image]

thats because a `margin` of 8 is added to the top and the left.

i tried adding `margin:-8 -8 8 8;` with no success. why??? and how can i fix this?

[DEMO fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/e9AAM/)

Comment: You're missing a unit, e.g. `px` http://jsfiddle.net/e9AAM/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you fogot to set a position. just add:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

since you havn't posted you complete markup, i can only assume your body has a margin or padding causing the shift you're seeing.

- [fiddle demonstratig the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HEjSU/)
- [fiddle with fix applied](http://jsfiddle.net/HEjSU/1/)

Answer (score 1):

simple thing to fix.

Add that to your CSS

```
* /*Remove all the default margin and padding*/
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body /*so it'll work when you specify 100% height on element*/
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

BTW: use units(`px`/`%`) for margin/padding other then 0.

and Here's a [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/e9AAM/6/)

also, You don't even need the `fixed` position for that.. check out that [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/e9AAM/7/)

Comment: u didnt read the question, or i am missing something, try making a fiddle.

Comment: you're clearly missing something.. [Here you Go](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/e9AAM/4/).

Comment: no it is ( `+1` ) i just removed `margin:-8 -8 8 8;`. thats all

Comment: oh.. sorry. also: you can use that without `fixed` (checkout the new fiddle)