# Extra space around footer element

Tags: html, css

I am getting an extra space both below and above my footer on my page, I have tried using margin:0; and padding also but it's still there.

here's my whole html code:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="images">
        <img src="f1.png" />
        <img src="linkedin.png" />
        <img src="t1.png" />
        <div id="menu">
            <img src="email1.png" />
            <img src="pen_marker.png" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    <img src="url.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

and here's my css part:

[image: you can see the spaces in the image]

```
body {
    margin:0;
}
#header {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -moz-box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    position: fixed;
}
#menu {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-right: 50%;
    float:right;
}
#menu img {
    padding-left:0;
}
#images img {
    margin-left:30px;
}
#main {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#main img {
    width:100%;
}
#footer {
    height:60px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NrxL4/

i am not able to figure out whether its because of inheritance or what.

### EDIT:

There is still space *below* the footer:

[image]

Comment: Check if you're using the right doctype (use `<!doctype html>` since you are using HTML5). And try using a [CSS reset](http://www.cssreset.com/) first.

Comment: Possible to include a screen-shot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Try adding `html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

Comment: I have used <!doctype html > only, but what is this CSS reset?

Comment: ya i uploaded a screen shot but it didnt uploaded...

Comment: ok the image is there now, thanks to Steve for editing

Comment: Isn't that space below the image your `#footer` with `height:60px`?

Comment: Sure looks like it to me. Base fiddle added. http://jsfiddle.net/NrxL4/

Comment: @showdave i have given the height 60px and its what i needed , the problem is the space

Comment: Do you have an online example (no fiddle)?

Comment: no... i have heard of fiddle just now, from your side... :p

Comment: @isherwood thanks for adding it to fiddle .., in that the space is visible...

Comment: You'll have to be more clear about what space you're referring to.

Comment: exactly 60px is the footer..the problem is the white space between the main image and the footer

Comment: I highly recommend you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485720/which-html5-reset-css-do-you-use-and-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you mean.

By default, images are inline elements.
If you set that image to `display:block`, the space goes away.

```
#main img {
    width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

Try it below:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  position: fixed;
}

#menu {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: 50%;
  float: right;
}

#menu img {
  padding-left: 0;
}

#images img {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

#main {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #00F;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="images">
    <img src="f1.png" />
    <img src="linkedin.png" />
    <img src="t1.png" />
    <div id="menu">
      <img src="email1.png" />
      <img src="pen_marker.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <img src="http://www.fundraising123.org/files/u16/bigstock-Test-word-on-white-keyboard-27134336.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VX8jy/2/)

Here is a screen-shot:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for that , it worked!
but there is still some white space below the footer how can i get rid of that??

Comment: That I cannot reproduce. Added a screen-shot to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#main img {
width:100%;
display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SEE this fiddle i have edited  this might solve your problem

`<div id="footer"></div>`

http://jsfiddle.net/NrxL4/2/

Comment: What is the solution? What did you change?

Comment: Maybe that's the wrong fiddle link? That seems to be the original code posted by @isherwood.

Comment: @showdev i just edited that same fiddle ... check margin-top added to the footer

Comment: You might have to click "update" to save your changes and generate a new link. I don't see the change.

Comment: thanks for the help, I have added margin-top:-05px; to my code but there is still space inn my code as shown in my second screenshot

Comment: its looking exactly as i wanted as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/NrxL4/2/ .... what have you added beside margin-top:-05px;???

Comment: @rahul if you are still getting white space below  try adding margin-bottom same way as i have addd margin-top n try

Comment: i have tried it already, I think its not because of margin bcause margin is the outermost space outside padding , so i guess it should be 0px; its some other thing.

Comment: @rahul ya might be but when i checked your file on chrome and IE it dint showed me that bottom space...

Answer (score 0):

About the space after footer, I have one question.
Are the scroll bars visible? Since I don't see any in the first screenshot. May be the page is not long enough to fit your screen size. Try adding some more content before footer and check if the spacing persists.

Regards

EDIT:

To stick the footer to the bottom use the following code-

```
footer {
    position:absolute;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    /* Include other footer properties */
}
```

I hope that helps :)

Comment: hmm i think its true, i dont needed any scroll bar

Comment: If you want the footer to simply stick to the bottom without getting the scrollbars, you can give the footer absolute positioning and set the bottom and left properties to zero. Also set the width to 100% so the footer expands to full width of the view port. see the edit above

Answer (score 0):

This fixed mine:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
}

footer {
display:flex; /* could be block as well */
position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

auto position for `fixed` is `top:8;` and `left:8;`. so add

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
```

to your `#header` css.

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209946/cover-div-adding-a-margin).

Comment: auto position?? but the space is around the footer