# Why is it margin: 0 on the paragraph element rather than the div element that contains it?

Tags: html, css

I have a header div that I want to be flush against the top of the window. When I enclose a paragraph in the div, space opens up between the top of the window and the div. The only way to close the space is to style the paragraph:

```
div#header p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Why does the browser, by default, create a margin for the paragraph outside the div that contains the paragraph?

Comment: Add a little more code, there could be a few reasons.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19209946/cover-div-adding-a-margin

Comment: If it is too much of an issue try using margin:0 on the html css

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why would margin not be contained by parent element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176520/why-would-margin-not-be-contained-by-parent-element)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it just does, dont worry too much about it. put some code in to remove the margin if you want (like) you did.

here is some good reset code if you want:

```
/*Remove all the default margin and padding*/
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body /*so it'll work when you specify 100% height on element*/
{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is likely due to **collapsing margins**. [MDN has a good article on the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing). Basically, top and bottom margins collapse together to form a single margin between elements. This allows for specifying `p {margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:10px;}` and having only `10px` of space between paragraphs (instead of `20px`).

See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/bfrohs/Pqsmx/) that shows collapsed margins versus non-collapsed margins.

You can find more information in the [CSS2 Box Model specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Answer (score 0):

If it is too much of an issue.

Add that to your CSS

```
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Every browser has it's own default CSS for html tags. For example, In chrome the margin before and after the `p` tag is `1em` which is equal to the `font-size` you set. While in Firefox, the `margin` is `0` expect from the bottom of the element, where it is `1em` again.

There are 'reset' stylesheets, that removes all special styling (like padding and margin) from (almost all) elements, so you can start 'fresh'. [Reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/) is a popular choice.